# Verbally agreed notice period - What do I do?

Tags: united-kingdom, quitting, notice-period

I gave notice to my HR Manager that I wanted to leave my job because of a new job offer. We verbally agreed on 4 weeks notice, even though my contract says that I should work a minimum of 3 months notice. The contract does, however, say 'By mutual agreement, these notice periods may be waived.' I set the wheels in motion with my new job contract and agreed on a start date on the Monday after the 4 weeks.

However, a senior manager has said to the HR Manager that they are not happy with this and wants me to work the 3 months. This is 3 days after we had agreed on the notice period. I am now being told that they can contact my new firm and let them know this. But how can they ask the new firm for a new start date without admitting to the fact that they agreed on a 4 week notice period? What options do I have to ensure that I can leave in 4 weeks time? In an ideal world I would leave today, because I hate my job and the situation that management has put me in. I am also worried that my new employer will not wait for 3 months, and I am really worried about missing this opportunity.

My plan at the moment is to send an email to the HR Manager requesting written confirmation. Although, I'm not sure the HR Manager will give this to me now she's been asked to increase my notice to 3 months.

Comment: "without admitting to the fact that they agreed on a 4 week notice period?" - They could do this easily, they don't mention it at all which incorrectly implies, you indicated it would be 4 weeks on your own.  You might be out of luck, looks like somebody with enough clout, is overruling your HR manager.

Comment: What country are you in?

Comment: @DanPichelman I am in the UK.

Comment: @Ramhound I think that might be the case. If I am able to get written confirmation that the HR Manager did grant me the 4 week notice period, do you think they would still be able to force me to work the 3 months?

Comment: @Jasmine13 - You signed a contract, that indicates you will work a 3-month notice, it sounds like you were told an exception would be made by somebody who didn't have the authority to grant it.  Yes;  It is very likely you will be forced to work the full 3 month notice period.  Is there a reason you even requested the 4 weeks instead of the 3 months, companies understand notice periods, you were clearly selected for a reason.  You were presumably selected, given a written offer, all before you indicated the notice period  you were required to work.

Comment: Is a 3 month notice period even legal in the UK?

Answer (score 9):

> My plan at the moment is to send an email to the HR Manager requesting
>   written confirmation.

That is the right plan. Get it in writing. Remind them of the verbal agreement and ask for written confirmation.

> Although, I'm not sure the HR Manager will give this to me now she's
>   been asked to increase my notice to 3 months.

That's out of your control. Often HR is supposed to run these sorts of "one-off" exceptions by the relevant manager. In this case they apparently failed to do so.

Perhaps they will offer you the option to buy out the remainder of your notice period. Perhaps not.

If they choose to hold you to the contracted 3 month notice period, I suspect there is little you can do about it other than to notify your new employer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will get it in writing to the HR Manager to hold her accountable for the verbal agreement.

Answer (score 4):

In this situation:

Send a "follow-up email confirming a verbal agreement" email.

The **FUECAVA email** is a critical element of business today.

> Steve.  Just to confirm our discussion on **Tuesday at 2pm**, you're kindly allowing me to leave after **four** weeks. That means, my **final day** I believe will be 37th Jan.  Thanks again for everything! Fattie.

cc'ing EVERYONE. Notice you've locking down what happened (while apparently being polite and helpful). The FUECAVA email is your friend.

Ideally you should have done that immediately after the verbal talk.

Comment: Thank you for this helpful comment. I will remember this for the future. I will send off the email tomorrow and report back.

Comment: good luck, @Jasmine13 !

Comment: seems like the only place on the interwebz that mentions FUECAVA

Comment: I don't think this will work after such a delay.  It might have if you had sent it immediately after the verbal agreement, but after there's been an objection it's highly unlikely to do any good.  Timing is everything here